# Custom fields woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am displaying some custom fields on the woocommerce single product page with this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary','add_custom_field', 20 );
function add_custom_field() {
   global $post;
   echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Brand', true );
   echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Content', true );
   return true;
}
```

This dispays only the values of the custom fields, but I would like the names before so it would look like this:

Brand:  ...
Content: ...

The custom fields don't aplly to every product though, so for the products where the custom fields are not set, nothing should be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_custom_field', 20 );
function add_custom_field() {
    global $post;
    $brand =   get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Brand', true );
    $content = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Content', true );
    if (!empty($brand)) {
        echo 'Brand: '. $brand .'<br>';
    }
    if (!empty($content)) {
        echo 'Content: '. $content .'<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_custom_field', 20 );
function add_custom_field() {
    global $post;
    $brand =   get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Brand', true );
    $content = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Content', true );
    if (!empty($brand)) {
        echo 'Brand: '. $brand;
    }
    if (!empty($content)) {
        echo 'Content: '. $content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, but both custom fields are diaplayed directly after each other. I would like them in a seperate line, can a <br> be added somehow?

Comment: yes you can add <br> after $brand like this 
echo 'Brand:'. $brand . '<br>';